# Aptana Studio 3 - constantly refreshing after SVN update

Tags: eclipse, svn, refresh, aptana

I just installed Aptana Studio 3   (built on Eclipse), and installed the Subversive-plugin too. After I svn-update my project (400 MB, 18.000 files , 2.000 folders ) Aptana keeps refreshing constantly. It seems about every folder in my project is being refreshed, even when only a few files are updated, which is causing some big lags when using Aptana.

I was using Zend Studio before, which didn't display this behaviour.

I already unchecked 'Refresh automatically' and 'Build automatically' in the Preferences.

Does anybody have an idea why this happens?

**UPDATE:**

I gave up on Aptana Studio 3. Too many weird things  (for example duplicate key bindings that CANNOT be disabled). I'm using the 'Eclipse for PHP'-package now and installed the Aptana plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is to go into Preferences->Aptana and uncheck the 'Auto-detect modifications to projects made outside IDE'. This will stop endless refreshes :)

Comment: is not there some way to exclude specific files or directories ?

Answer (score 1):

Try unchecking the `Refresh automatically' option from Window > Preferences > General > Workspace

Answer (score 0):

Aptana routinely hangs especially when saving a file.
 "Re-indexing (incremental ..." is most common for me.

Marking /tmp directory as "Derived" (right-click Properties checkbox) has stopped the irritating delay when saving files.

Then as /tmp/cache has 1000's of files actively added to it, eclipse is not constantly trying to "refresh/re-index" the workspace because of new files.

To try and further prove and validate this point:

1) /tmp/cache is "Derived" (for last 2 hours)

2) Modified and saved 20 files in a row with ZERO delay by Eclipse/Aptana.

3) Unchecked "Derived" on /tmp (or /tmp/cache) folder.

4) Modified one file, saved, and I waited ~30 seconds for the file to save because Aptana had to "re-index".  Of course it is always upon saving.

5) 5 minutes later, with background processes running which have added 7000+ files to /tmp/cache, I tried to modify and save the same file and had to wait ~10 seconds.